# How to scrape data from nested div tags and export to CSV from dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, scrape

i'm trying to export the div tags 'prod-details' from [here](http://www.wheelfire.com/scontent/WheelResults.cfm?sortwheels=&VehicleMakeFinal=Acura&VehicleYearFinal=2016&VehicleModelFinal=ILX&VehicleOption=1.5L%20Hybrid&VehicleOptionFinal=1.5L%20Hybrid&wheelsize=16&isCar=1) I wanted to know if there is a way or script I can run in the chrome dev tools that would export a CSV with the data scraped?

Answer (score 1):

Kayce is probably right not to do it for you, but it can be hard to get started, so here's a basic implementation with comments that you can work from. Please do read and try to understand it rather than just copy and pasting it.

```
// Create a list of the selectors within each prod-deatils you'd like to export as a column
var columnSelectors = [".brand", ".model", ".finish", ".ProductPriceDetails"];

// Create an array with the column selectors at the top to act as a header
[columnSelectors.join(",")].concat(
    // Grab the product details and arrayify it so we can use standard array functions
    $(".prod-details").toArray()
        // These are elements, and we want to be able to use jquery with them, so wrap each element with jquery
        .map(d => $(d))
        // For each prod-detail element, we want to extract each of the columns
        .map(d =>
            columnSelectors.map(
                // ... so we iterate the selectors and apply each one to the product, grab the text and trim() it to remove whitespace
                sel => d.find(sel).text().trim()
            ).join(",") // Finally join each of the columns with a comma so it follows CSV format
        )
).join("\n"); // And join all the rows with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to implement it for you ;) but I think this workflow will get you most of the way there.

1. Create a [snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets).
2. Scrape the data within your snippet. `document.querySelectorAll('.prod-details')` will get you started.
3. Format the data to CSV in your snippet.
4. Use XHR to send the CSV-formatted-data to Google Sheets (or some other relevant service) in your snippet.
5. Run the snippet while the page is open.